# css and html height and width?

Tags: html, css

When I zoom in or out my element is moving and I've tried every code I know but it's still the same, so I've posted my html and css code and I hope you can help me. I have this problem with every element I put in my page

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>    //html code
<html>
  <head>       // head tag

    <title></title>                    

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="untitled2.css"  /> //css link
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html":charset-windows-1256">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="menu">  // div for menu 
<ul>
<li>link</li>
<li>link</li>
<li>link</li>       // ul li
<li>link</li>
<li>link</li>
</ul>
</div>

  </body>
</html>       // closing html



          //  css

body  {
    background-image: url('3.jpg');
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% ;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-width:600px;          //body attribute 
    max-width:2000px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;

}


#menu{
margin-top: 380px;
padding: 0px; 
background-color:#555258; //menu attribute 
width:2500px;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "element" and "moving"?

Comment: @ Josef Engelfrost maybe after you take look to the pictures [link](http://www.4shared.com/download/r7HaSxANce/1__1_.jpg?lgfp=1000) this when i am at the 100% zooming and the other when i increase zooming [link] (http://www.4shared.com/download/A6j1zENsce/2_online.jpg?lgfp=1000) can you see how its goes out from the menu body and the same thing happened when i design table

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting the width and height to 100% and also setting min and max width? If you are trying to make sure it will look right regardless of the device used to view your site, look at this tutorial.
http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/responsive-design-a-crash-course-and-demo/

Comment: i try it but it's not working i hope you have another solution here's my problem  take look to the pictures [link](http://www.4shared.com/download/r7HaSxANce/1__1_.jpg?lgfp=1000) this when i am at the 100% zooming and the other when i increase zooming [link] (http://www.4shared.com/download/A6j1zENsce/2_online.jpg?lgfp=1000) can you see how its goes out from the menu body and the same thing happened when i design table

Comment: Are you trying to make a drop down menu? You could look at www.dynamicdrive.com for some menus. You can incorporate them into a responsive design.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve  is making my site display in every platforms

Comment: You need to use responsive design css. The tutorial will explain. Also google responsive design if you need more examples. The css code you are using is not right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a wild guess here, because it's not clear to me what you want to achieve, but I hope something is helpful.

I'll start from a blank slate.

```css
/* Styles go here */

.menu {
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center; /* Center text */
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-block; /* Place the list items on inline (on the same row) */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Is this a good start?